# How to change the shape of a button in PyQt5

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to make up/down/left/right arrows on my GUI with PyQt but I can't seem to find any information on how to change the shape of a QPushButton into anything but a rectangle or oval. Is there a way to make the buttons appear arrow-shaped? If so, please give an example of how you would do this. (I am using Python 3 and PyQt5, NOT QT nor Designer)

Comment: The appearance can be customized by implementing the `paintEvent()`, and that could also work for the shape (which could be achieved using `setMask()` too), but the problem could be proper positioning and interaction, especially if you want to put those widgets in positions that could potentially overlap their bounding rect (widgets **always** have rectangular geometries). A further possibility would be to use a custom widget for *all* those buttons (and implement painting and mouse interaction), or, even better, a QGraphicsView.